# What is the voltage range on ADC's inputs? Photodiode + TIA + ADC

Tags: adc, photodiode, differential-amplifier

[image: photodiode + TIA circuit + ADC inputs]

Can someone here help me understand this circuit better? It's a photodiode -> transimpedance amplifier (TIA) -> ADC.

- What is the voltage range on the ADC's inputs? AIN- and AIN+.
- Which input is "fixed" and which "moves" according to the amount of light?
- What is the voltage on the op-amps' negative inputs?

Comment: Always expect the maximum supply voltage range on opamp outputs if considering circuit ruggedness. The regular signal level depends on diode current of course.

Comment: What kind of ADC? Looks like a way to drive a fully differential ADC input.

Comment: Why did you chose Zero Bias mode and Diff output?

Comment: @glen_geek it's the ADS1256

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I am not sure what is Zero Bias mode. ADC is configured in differential mode for maximum resolution - because we measure reflection of near-infrared light with the photodiode so the signals are small. I don't have formal EE background, so explanations or pointers to learning resources are welcome

Comment: I explained in my answer. 2.5V on both sides means 0V across diode. Are these reflections pulsed ? Report intensity and duration. In your question.  -5V bias is more sensitive than 0V but depends on your level relative to dark current

Answer (score 0):

> What is the voltage range on the ADC's inputs? AIN- and AIN+.

At most, the maximum output voltage is limited by the characteristics particular op-amp and the supply voltage you are giving it. This is in the opamp datasheet.

In below this maximum limit, the output voltage is limited by the maximum illumination expected by your application and the responsivity of the photodiode. You need to know your maximum illumination and look at the photodiode datasheet. Usually in the form of a graph. Then you use that with the gain of your circuit.

> What is the voltage on the op-amps' negative inputs?

This answer is virtually identical to the first question. Know the intensity and look at the opamp and photodiode datasheets.

> Which input is "fixed" and which "moves" according to the amount of light?

In a single-ended signal, there are two wires:

- one is labelled 0V and is treated as the reference voltage
- the other carries the signal
- the signal is treated as the difference in voltage between these two wires

In a differential signal, there are three wires:

- one is labelled as 0V but is not the signal reference
- the other two wires carry the signal
- The other two wires both carry the signal and the voltage on both can change relative to ground (and thus also relative each other). The signal is treated as the voltage difference between these two wires. They are each other's reference.

Your circuit output is obviously the differential kind.

For the purposes in your question, you can split the circuit into separate single-ended TIA circuits and fix the end of the photodiode with the missing op-amp to 2.5V.

Comment: Wrong, the input is also differential and if the outputs are not railed, the inputs  will always be 2.5V

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Hmmm yes. Well I suppose an easy way to go about it it is to fix one end of the photodiode to 2.5V and split the circuit.

Comment: Both ends and output are already 2.5V with no dark current, adding offset also adds dark current but increases linearity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is the photodiode's [datasheet](https://www.micro-semiconductor.com/datasheet/1e-SD003-151-001.pdf) could you help me focus on the right bits of it? What do I need to learn in order to understand how to estimate maximum expected output current? How is "illumination" measured/calculated/estimated? It's a near-infrared LED like [this](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2648670.pdf) flashing from ~30mm distance

Comment: Not much reflection of a wide cone on a tiny PD there. You have the wrong design. What response do you expect /need ?  List all variables in question!!!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the voltage range on the ADC's inputs? AIN- and AIN+.

That depends on the wavelength and sensitivity 0.5 to 1 [mA/mW], wave power mW, and area, reduced down to chip size in \$mm^2\$ to get mA received then Vo=-In*Rfb(=240k).  However, all diodes have maximum capacitance rated at 0V and your differential circuit applies 2.5V to both sides so virtual null is the same on both sides or Vr=0V rather than Vr=-5V as specified in the sensitivity.  That approach is used for low frequency , high intensity flashes of light.  This is also known as the **Zero Bias or Photovoltaic Mode.** The voltage produced has a very small dynamic range (compressed non-linear characteristic. )

> Which input is "fixed" and which "moves" according to the amount of light?

Only the current moves, both voltages are fixed but since the relative direction is opposite on inputs, the outputs are complementary voltages, thus requiring bipolar supplies which you do not have, so that will not work.  Just use one TIA with cathode biased to 5V and anode input biased in the lower common-mode range on Vin+ where input offset voltage, Vio vs Vcm is minimized such as at 1.0V

> What is the voltage on the op-amps' negative inputs?

All inputs and outputs should be 2.5V with no light input.

Comment: What I could understand from your answer (with my current EE knowledge) is that:  
1. it's not trivial to calculate theoretical current output from the photodiode  
2. the way I use the photodiode here is called Photovoltaic or Zero Bias mode. Description sounds appropriate for our application
3. the circuit is not designed correctly. I should simplify/redesign the TIA wiring  

Is this correct? Any resources for learning about TIA for zero-biased photodiodes?
Idea is to measure reflections of near-infrared light with the diode (NIR spectrometer, plastic scanner project)